# Error when verify install chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an error "Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be initated by a user gesture."

With this code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Titre de la page</title>
      <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajhifddimkapgcifgcodmmfdlknahffk">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        chrome.webstore.install();
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      test Chrome
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why as i follow the google tuto : https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (I have italicized the important part):

> ### Triggering inline installation
>
> To actually begin inline installation, the `chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)` function must be called. *This function can only be called in response to a user gesture, for example within a click event handler; an exception will be thrown if it is not.*

You cannot just put the `install()` call in a script tag and have it run automatically.